# Every 500 times do a Sleep()

Tags: php, sleep

my database has 25000 rows.
Using a While-loop i get the data.

Now i want to use SLEEP() everytime 500 rows are picked up.

I created the script below, but this script only works one time at 500 rows.

```
<?php
$i=0;

while($value = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

if($i == 500) {

// sleep for 10 seconds
sleep(10);

}

//continue


$i++;

}
?>
```

How to mainupulate this script to make it work every 500 rows?

Comment: you mean ($i % 500 === 0) ?

Comment: Use the *modulo*-function like `if ($i%500 == 0)`

Comment: Can I ask? Why you need sleep in this situation?

Comment: Maybe he thinks it helps database to rest LOL

Comment: Hey Plutov,

i'm sending mails to all of my members, so i don't want the mailsystem to blow up. So i'm building in a sleep().
Maybe there's a better way, if so, i'm glad to hear it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace `($i == 500)` by `($i%500 == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$i=0;

while($value = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   if($i % 500 == 0) {

      // sleep for 10 seconds
      sleep(10);

   }

   //continue
   $i++;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this**

```
  while($value = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {


 if($i % 500 == 0) {

  // sleep for 10 seconds
 sleep(10);

  }

 //continue


 $i++;

 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

check `$i%500`

```
<?php
$i=0;

while($value = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

if($i%500 == 0) {

// sleep for 10 seconds
sleep(10);

}

//continue


$i++;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$i = 0;

while($value = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    if(++$i % 500 === 0) {

        // sleep for 10 seconds
        sleep(10);

    }

}
?>
```